# How can I access an Instance Store Volume in an ECS Task?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a Docker image that downloads a large data set, processes it, creating a ton of temporary files in the process and then uploads the final result to S3. I don't need the temp files to be persistent / survive an instance failure, so I want to use instance store for this. For some reason, Docker refuses to use it though.

In my Launch Configuration, I selected an instance type with instance store (c3.8xlarge), then added the two Instance Store volumes as /dev/xvdcz and /dev/sdb.

In the user data, I mount the sdb volume and make it writable:

```
sudo mkdir /media/storage
sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/storage
sudo chmod o+rw /media/storage
```

In the task definition, I create a volume named "InstanceStorage" with the source path "/media/storage" and in the container definition, I added a Mount Point for this volume at /storage.

When I now ssh into the instance while the task is running, and I look at the host's /media/storage directory, it's empty. The task logs clearly show that it can write to the /storage directory of the container. It's just much smaller than the Instance Store - 7.8 GB available instead of 300.

I tried to manually run the Docker container and attach the volume:

```
docker run -it -v /media/storage:/storage --entrypoint /bin/sh my-docker-image:latest
```

Same behavior: I can write to /storage, the files even survive exiting and restarting the Docker container, but it's way too small and any files I create in /storage inside the container don't exist in /media/storage on the host.

Looking at df -h at both the host and the container, it becomes clear that **it mounted /dev/xvda1 instead** -- the volume that also stores the docker images.

Host:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7,8G  848M  6,9G  11% /
devtmpfs         30G   88K   30G   1% /dev
tmpfs            30G     0   30G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb       315G   67M  299G   1% /media/storage
```

Container:

```
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-(...)  9.8G  1.1G  8.2G  12% /
tmpfs                      30G     0   30G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      30G     0   30G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1                7.8G  848M  6.9G  11% /storage
shm                        64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
```

Why would it do that?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution. [This script](https://gist.github.com/kamermans/176c190670a163b1147e) pointed me in the right direction.

**You need to restart the Docker service.**

Apparently, Docker starts before the user data scripts are executed, and it can only access volumes that were mounted when the service started.

So I added this to the end of my userdata script, and that fixed it:

```
sudo service docker restart
```